# Qt - set a specific/fixed character width for QTextEdit

Tags: qt

It's common that each character has a particular width. But I found that in Sublime Text 3, each character has the same width. Is that possible to do the same thing for QTextEdit?

**Sublime Text 3:**

[image]

**My QTextEdit:**

[image]

Comment: For that purpose you should use a monospace font. For example Courier or Consolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have all characters of the same width you should use a monospace fonts. Here is an example:

```
QTextEdit te;
te.setFont({ "Courier" });
te.setText("iiii\nwwww");
te.show();
```

Comment: I recommend [QFontDatabase::systemFont(QFontDatabase::FixedFont)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontdatabase.html#SystemFont-enum) so that the target system can choose the font

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto textedit = new QTextEdit;
    QFont font("Monospace");
    textedit->setFont(font);
    textedit->setText("Hello\nWorld!");
    textedit->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```